# Crashlytics's stack trace looks impossible (Android + Proguard)

Tags: java, android, exception, proguard, crashlytics

I recently updated my app and there is one exception that occurs a lot. When I look at Crashlytics summary I saw this stacktrace:

```
[Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException]

com.company.app.model.ClassA.method1
com.company.app.model.ClassB.method2
com.company.app.view.ClassB.onTouch
android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent (View.java:7241)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2174)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:1875)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2174)
.....
```

From my understanding, there is no line number shown on the top 3 lines because I use Proguard to obfuscate the app.

But what baffled me is that, it is not possible that ClassA.method1 is called directly or indirectly by ClassB.method2 (I have checked it multiple times). So now I am stuck. Does this mean that the name of methods shown here is inaccurate? And if that is the case, how should I proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: You might get more stacktrace information by using the proguard rule `-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable`, as [suggested](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/202143-eclipse-with-proguard) by crashlyitics.

Comment: @NoActivity.java is right :) Here're the docs for more info: http://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html

Comment: Thanks guys. You are correct. I add -keepattributes flag in and suddenly the method names change to the correct ones!